# shorten the value by underscore in Vertica

Tags: vertica

We need to remove the 3rd segment (e0025895) and 7th segment (xxxx) to shorten the value in Vaertica. Please refer the sample data input and required output.

**Value:**

source_data_e0025895_pw2_px_77892_xxxx

east_match_a569820_kw2_lk_8975_p2585

**Shorten Value:**

source_data_pw2_px_77892

east_match_kw2_lk_8975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working

```
select 
 split_part(value, '_', 1) || '_' ||
 split_part(value, '_', 2) || '_' ||
 split_part(value, '_', 4) || '_' ||
 split_part(value, '_', 5) || '_' ||
 split_part(value, '_', 6) as Shorten_value
from mytable;
```

Comment: split_part() is not SQL Server.    Please tag responsibly